# main Class won't load on a different computer

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a program that evaluates simple math equations and it works fine. But I sent it to someone else and they couldn't use as they said that the main class won't load but I am not sure what I did wrong. The class name and java file are spelled the exact same way so is there something I am missing here?

Comment: What is the code that you sent? Can you provide an example?

Comment: can you show us how the class looks like?? it can be a package problem\

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson you have no way of knowing this is a duplicate of the one you've marked without further information.